# php $_POST of UTF-8 characters is getting converted to CP1251

Tags: php, codenameone

I am using the below code to post french characters to a php page  (this is a super simplified test case)

```
ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest() {
    ...
};
r.setUrl(GLOBALS.BASEURL + "/login.php");
r.setPost(true);
r.addArgument("test", "Léçon");
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
```

This creates the following post to the server:

```
Post Body:
    test=L%C3%A9%C3%A7on
Post Headers:
    cookie=[PHPSESSID=eo07gkat0fsmpjksmg30qkk162]
    User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (iPod; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5]
    Content-Type=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8]
```

However by the time I get the $_POST variable it seems to be coded in CP1251

```
<?php
session_start();
error_log("FINDME all vars:" . print_r($_POST, true));
```

Produces the following in the error log  (looks like CP1251):

```
[Sun Dec 20 ...] FINDME all vars:Array\n(\n    [test] => L\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa7on\n)\n
```